# Multiple Groupings on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Forgive any bad wording as I'm rather new to Pandas. I've done a fair amount of Googling but can't quite figure out the keywords I need to get the answer I'm looking for. I have some rather simple data containing counts of a certain flag grouped by IDs and dates, similar to the below:

```
id        date          flag   count
-------------------------------------
CAZ1      02/03/2012    Y      12
CAZ1      02/03/2012    N      7
CAZ2      03/03/2012    Y      6
CAZ2      03/03/2012    N      2
CRI2      02/03/2012    Y      14
CRI2      02/03/2012    G      5
LMU3      01/12/2013    G      7
LMU4      02/12/2013    G      4
LMU5      01/12/2014    G      3
LMU6      01/12/2014    G      2
LMU7      05/12/2014    G      2
EUR4      01/16/2014    N      3
```

What I'm looking to do is group the IDs by certain flag **combinations**, sum their counts, and then get means for these per year. Resulting data should look something like:

```
        2012        2013        2014        Mean Calculations:
--------------------------------------
Y,N |   6.75        NaN         NaN         (((12+7)/2)+((6+2)/2))/2
--------------------------------------
Y,G |   9.5         NaN         NaN         (14+5)/2         
--------------------------------------
G   |   NaN         5.5         2.33        (7+4)/2, (3+2+2)/3
--------------------------------------
N   |   NaN         NaN         3           (3)
```

Not sure if this makes sense. I think I need to perform multiple GroupBys at the same time, with the option to define the different criteria for each of the different groupings.

Happy to clarify further if needed. My initial attempts at coding this have been filled with errors so I don't think there's much benefit in posting progress so far. In fact, I just tried to write something and it seemed more misleading than helpful. Sorry, >_<.

Comment: You've changed the calculation you want, but I don't understand why you want Y,G/2012 to be 19.  Shouldn't it be (14+5)/2?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Apologies.

Comment: Actually, I've completely confused myself and the original answer/question is more correct (using sum)... but I'll leave it as-is so that it doesn't get too messy if someone else comes across it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can get what you want by first doing a `groupby` and then building a `pivot_table`:

[original version]

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
grouped = df.groupby(["id","date"], as_index=False)
df_new = grouped.agg({"flag": ",".join, "count": "sum"})
df_new["year"] = df_new["date"].dt.year
df_final = df_new.pivot_table(index="flag", columns="year")
```

produces

```
>>> df_final
     count               
year  2012 2013      2014
flag                     
G      NaN  5.5  2.333333
N      NaN  NaN  3.000000
Y,G   19.0  NaN       NaN
Y,N   13.5  NaN       NaN
```

[updated after the question was edited]

If you want the mean instead of the sum, just write `mean` instead of `sum` when doing the aggregation, i.e.

```
df_new = grouped.agg({"flag": ",".join, "count": "mean"})
```

which gives

```
>>> df_final
     count               
year  2012 2013      2014
flag                     
G      NaN  5.5  2.333333
N      NaN  NaN  3.000000
Y,G   9.50  NaN       NaN
Y,N   6.75  NaN       NaN
```

---

The only tricky part is passing the dictionary to `agg` so we can perform two aggregation operations at once:

```
>>> df_new
     id       date  count flag  year
0  CAZ1 2012-02-03     19  Y,N  2012
1  CAZ2 2012-03-03      8  Y,N  2012
2  CRI2 2012-02-03     19  Y,G  2012
3  EUR4 2014-01-16      3    N  2014
4  LMU3 2013-01-12      7    G  2013
5  LMU4 2013-02-12      4    G  2013
6  LMU5 2014-01-12      3    G  2014
7  LMU6 2014-01-12      2    G  2014
8  LMU7 2014-05-12      2    G  2014
```

It's usually easier to work with these flat formats as much as you can and then pivot only at the end.

For example, if your real dataset is more complicated than the one you posted, you might need another `groupby` -- but that's easy enough using this pattern.

Comment: Ok, so this gets me most of the way there... thanks!! It does raise some more questions at the end with how to pivot/filter/group the df_new dataset (I'd like to group all items that have 'G' anywhere in them **as well as** something else, separately group just the 'G's, etc.) but hopefully I can do this using another group/agg as you suggest.